# How to create dependent DropDown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

```
public IActionResult Add(int? id)
{
    Project team2 = new Project();
    List<Project> teams = new List<Project>();
    team2 = _context.Project
        .FirstOrDefault(m => m.ProjectId == id);
    teams.Add(team2);
    ViewBag.Project = teams;
    ViewBag.Teams = _context.Team.ToList();
    ViewBag.Members = _context.Member.ToList();
    ViewBag.Roles = _context.Role.ToList();
    return View();
}
```

This is Controller of my dropdown I want dependent drop down if i click on Teams It shows those Member that can be Available in that Team not other

```
<div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 8px; padding-right:7px;">
    <label asp-for="Team" class="control-label"></label>
    <br />
    <select asp-for="TeamId" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.Teams,"TeamId","TeamName"))">
    </select>
</div>
<br />

<div class="form-group" style="padding-top:8px; padding-right:7px;">
    <label asp-for="Member" class="control-label"></label>
    <br />
    <select asp-for="MemberId" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.Members,"MemberId","Name"))">
    </select>
</div>
<br />
```

This is my HtmlCss Part.

Please Create JavasSript File for my project.

**Update:**

```
 public class Project
 {
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string? ProjectName { get; set; }


    public string? Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }

    public DateTime? End { get; set; }

    public string? ProjectHead { get; set; }

    public string? Status { get; set; }

    public string? Technology { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProjectMember>? ProjectMembers { get; set; }
}
public class Member
{
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]

    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public string? Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public string? MaritalStatus { get; set; }
    public string? Address { get; set; }
    public long PhoneNo { get; set; }
    public string? Skills { get; set; }
    public string? Hobbies { get; set; }
    public string? JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string? Technology { get; set; }

    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public Team? Team { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TeamMember>? TeamMembers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProjectMember>? ProjectMembers { get; set; }

}
public class ProjectMember
{
    public int ProjectMemberId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public Project? Project { get; set; }
    public Member? Member { get; set; }
    public Role? Role { get; set; }
    public Team? Team { get; set; }
}
public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string? RoleName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TeamMember>? TeamMembers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProjectMember>? ProjectMembers { get; set; }
}
public class Team
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(60,MinimumLength =3)]
    public string? TeamName { get; set; }

    public string? ManagerName { get; set; }

    public string? TeamDescription { get; set; }

    public int ProjectDone { get; set; }

    public List<Member>? Members { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TeamMember>? TeamMembers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProjectMember>? ProjectMembers { get; set; }

}
public class TeamMember
{
    public int TeamMemberId { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set;}

    public Member? Member { get; set; }
    public Role? Role { get; set; }
    public Team? Team { get; set; }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a whole working demo:

Model:

```
public class Team
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public List<Member> Members { get; set; }
}
public class Member
{
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }
}
public class ViewModel
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }
    public List<int> MemberId { get; set; }
    public Member Member { get; set; }
}
```

View:

You use `MultiSelectList` for Member, guessing you may want to use multi select for Member selectlist.

If though, be sure add `multiple` to the select element or make the `MemberId` type of `List<string>`/`List<int>`.

```
@model ViewModel
<div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 8px; padding-right:7px;">
    <label asp-for="Team" class="control-label"></label>
    <br />
    <select asp-for="TeamId" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.Teams,"TeamId","TeamName"))">
          <option value="0">--Select All--</option>
    </select>
</div>
<br />

<div class="form-group" style="padding-top:8px; padding-right:7px;">
    <label asp-for="Member" class="control-label"></label>
    <br />
    <select asp-for="MemberId" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.Members,"MemberId","Name"))" >
    </select>
</div>
<br />

@section scripts{
    <script>
        $("#TeamId").change(function () {
            $.get("/Home/GetMember", { id: $("#TeamId").val() }, function (data) {
                $("#MemberId").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                    $("#MemberId").append("<option value='" + row.memberId + "'>" + row.name + "</option>")
                });
            });
        })
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Add(int? id)
{
    ViewBag.Teams = _context.Team.ToList();
    ViewBag.Members = _context.Member.ToList();
    return View();
}
public IActionResult GetMember(int id)
{
    var member = _context.Member.Where(a => a.TeamId == id)
                                .Select(a => new { 
                                    a.MemberId,
                                    a.Name
                                })
                                .ToList();
    return Json(member);
}
```

Result:

[image]

**Update:**

From your model design, `Team` and `Member`, `Project` and `Member`, `Team` and `Project`, their relationship should be many to many. Then `Role` and `ProjectMember`, `Role` and `TeamMember` should be one to many. You miss a third class to define the relationship between `Team` and `Project`. Other modification you could check the code below:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string? ProjectName { get; set; }


    public string? Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }

    public DateTime? End { get; set; }

    public string? ProjectHead { get; set; }

    public string? Status { get; set; }

    public string? Technology { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProjectMember>? ProjectMembers { get; set; }
    //add this....
    public ICollection<ProjectTeam>? ProjectTeams { get; set; }

}
public class Member
{
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]

    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public string? Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public string? MaritalStatus { get; set; }
    public string? Address { get; set; }
    public long PhoneNo { get; set; }
    public string? Skills { get; set; }
    public string? Hobbies { get; set; }
    public string? JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string? Technology { get; set; }

    //public int TeamId { get; set; }
    //public Team? Team { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TeamMember>? TeamMembers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProjectMember>? ProjectMembers { get; set; }

}
public class ProjectMember
{
    public int ProjectMemberId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    //public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public Project? Project { get; set; }
    public Member? Member { get; set; }
    public Role? Role { get; set; }
    //public Team? Team { get; set; }
}
public class ProjectTeam
{
    public int ProjectTeamId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public Project? Project { get; set; }
    public Team? Team { get; set; }
}
public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string? RoleName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TeamMember>? TeamMembers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProjectMember>? ProjectMembers { get; set; }
}
public class Team
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string? TeamName { get; set; }

    public string? ManagerName { get; set; }

    public string? TeamDescription { get; set; }

    public int ProjectDone { get; set; }

    //public List<Member>? Members { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TeamMember>? TeamMembers { get; set; }
    //public ICollection<ProjectMember>? ProjectMembers { get; set; }

    //add this....
    public ICollection<ProjectTeam>? ProjectTeams { get; set; }

}
public class TeamMember
{
    public int TeamMemberId { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public Member? Member { get; set; }
    public Role? Role { get; set; }
    public Team? Team { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: **When i Add Column like public int Team Team{get; set;} that will not work without migration the exception will pop no such column TeamId when i can migrate it show error like**  _SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'._

Comment: Hmmm, `public int Team Team {get; set;}`? You misspell something. Check my answer more detailed. And the `ViewModel` is not used to migrate to database.

Comment: no i can migrate **team id** in member class

Comment: Hmmm, pls answer my question correctly.... I never ask you for migrate the class. This does not relate to your current question. For the migration error, it makes before handling your original question. Any way, you need share your whole model design no only the member class and edit the question instead of sharing it in the comment.

Comment: I have  added model class in my question

Comment: is it ok? or do you want any other thing like controller view and view model

Comment: By using your current model, did you get the error `Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ProjectMember_Team_TeamId' on table 'ProjectMember' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths`?

Comment: yeah. **SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.**

Comment: I have to say...Your model design is in a mess. From your current model design, several table's relationship are conflict. I clarify it and give the correct model design. Update the answer later.

Comment: Actually, it is the deduced result from your model design. It is better for you to explain to us what do you want for these models.

Comment: I am making a project called Team Management.so i want to store all the information in it.so i made these classes.like member information team information and how many member in a team name of member and similar in project

Comment: and how can we add dependent dropdown?

Comment: Hmmm, I suggest you can check my answer.....